# How to view the context of each pod

Tags: kubernetes

I created a pod with context:

```
kubectl config set-context DevDan-context \
--cluster=kubernetes \
--namespace=development \
--user=DevDan
```

I see the pod if I run `kubectl --context=DevDan-context get pods`.

But if I run just `kubectl get pods`  I don't see the pod.

Is there a way to show all the pods with the column of context?
I know there is `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` but it just show the pods and doesn't write what context each pod has:

```
ubuntu@HOST:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
development   nginx-8586cf59-plq29                       1/1       Running   0          19h
kube-system   etcd-HOST                                  1/1       Running   1          9d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-HOST                        1/1       Running   1          9d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-HOST               1/1       Running   1          9d
kube-system   kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-25ddh                   3/3       Running   3          9d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-5vgd9                      1/1       Running   1          9d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-vvstn                      1/1       Running   0          9d
kube-system   kube-proxy-62xrx                           1/1       Running   1          9d
kube-system   kube-proxy-g7w7l                           1/1       Running   0          9d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-HOST                        1/1       Running   1          9d
```

The workaround is to run `kubectl config get-contexts` and then take each context and run `kubectl --context=<my_context> get pods` but if I have lots of context it can be problematic.

I also tried to run

Answer (score 1):

`set-context` sets attributes of a given context

`use-context` switches to it as the default, so that `get pods` with no --context arg uses it by default

Comment: But if I don't know what is the `context` ? How can I get the list of all the pods together with the context of each pod ?

Comment: pods don't have context. context is part of the local configuration file that names a specific combination of server, user credentials, and working namespace, so you can reference it when running a kubectl command. If you want to get pods across all namespaces, do `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

Answer (score 1):

To fetch all pods along with configuration:

```
kubectl describe pods --all-namespaces
```